# How to change from one text field to another

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a 4 text fields which are meant to be used to type in a 4 digit code sent to the phone. How can I automatically change to the next field if a number is written and for it not to take anything apart from numbers
Ill attach a picture along with my code base
[image]

```
// flow
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import { signup } from '../../assets/images';
import FormDiv from '../shared/Sign-in-div';
import ImageDiv from '../shared/Image-div';
import { Nunito32, Nunito20 } from '../shared/nunito/nunito';
import ImageContainer from '../shared/image-container';
import OtpField from '../shared/otp-field';
import PinkButton from '../shared/button-color-pink';

let [fieldOne, fieldTwo, fieldThree, fieldFour] = useRef(null);

const onChange = field => {
  field.focus();
};

const SignUpVerification = () => (
  <div style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
    <FormDiv style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
      <Nunito32
        style={{
          display: 'inline-block',
          textAlign: 'center',
          marginRight: 236,
          marginLeft: 200,
        }}
      >
        Verify your mobile number by entering the code we sent you
      </Nunito32>
      <div style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
        <OtpField
          ref={input => {
            fieldOne = input;
          }}
          style={{ marginRight: 10.5 }}
          onChange={() => onChange(fieldTwo)}
        />
        <OtpField
          ref={input => {
            fieldTwo = input;
          }}
          onChange={() => onChange(fieldThree)}
          style={{ marginRight: 10.5 }}
        />
        <OtpField
          ref={input => {
            fieldThree = input;
          }}
          onChange={() => onChange(fieldFour)}
          style={{ marginRight: 10.5 }}
        />
        <OtpField
          ref={input => {
            fieldFour = input;
          }}
          style={{ marginRight: 10.5 }}
        />
      </div>

      <PinkButton style={{ marginTop: 75 }}>Continue</PinkButton>
      <Nunito20>Send again</Nunito20>
    </FormDiv>
    <ImageContainer>
      <ImageDiv bg={signup} src={signup} alt="logo" />
    </ImageContainer>
  </div>
);

export default SignUpVerification;
```

It now gives me 2 errors that fieldOne is created but not used and ×
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

Answer (score 0):

How about re-render when the state you change?

Answer (score 0):

Handling focus is good task for [Refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#when-to-use-refs) in React. So idea will be to have refs for input fields and in `onChange` event handler check if user typed 3 digits and turn focus to next input.

I have created [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/focusswitch-54pks) on codesandbox to showcase how it works

Answer (score 0):

Since you are making use of `React JS`, you can go forward with [React Refs and the DOM](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) where you can select the nodes and handle the focus pragmatically. This is a sample implementation. Find the implementation [here](https://jsfiddle.net/h8rw21jy/).

```js
class App extends React.Component{
  componentDidMount(){
    this.fieldOne.focus();
  }
  onChange(field) {
   field.focus();
  }
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <input
          onChange={() => this.onChange(this.fieldTwo)}
          ref={(input) => { this.fieldOne = input; }} 
          placeholder="First Field" 
        />
        <input 
          onChange={() => this.onChange(this.fieldThree)}
          ref={(input) => { this.fieldTwo = input; }} 
          placeholder="Second Field" 
        />
        <input 
          onChange={() => this.onChange(this.fieldFour)}
          ref={(input) => { this.fieldThree = input; }}  
          placeholder="Third Field" 
        />
        <input 
          ref={(input) => { this.fieldFour = input; }} 
          placeholder="Fourth Field"
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
    
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.1/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/15.6.1/react-dom.min.js"></script>

 <div class="container-fluid" id="main">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div id="root"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems its not complete? where is the field one and so one being created?

Comment: @SImonHaddad the fieldOne, fieldTwo, fieldThree and fieldFour are the respective referral for the input fields.

Comment: I was not able to make it work, I tried declaring them using ```React.createRef()```